# Optimize JOIN -> GROUP BY query in PostgreSQL: all indexes are already there

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, query-optimization

There are at least a couple of similar (but **not exactly the same**) questions on SO. In those questions the problem around query performance is about lack of indices or excess predicates.

But my case is simple and clear: 3 tables, each one references another. There are BTree indices on **every referenced table row**. Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE region(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   title VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE unit(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   region_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES region(id)
);

CREATE TABLE unit_usage(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   title VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   unit_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES unit(id)
);

CREATE INDEX ON unit ((region_id));
CREATE INDEX ON unit_usage ((unit_id));
CREATE INDEX ON unit_usage ((title));
```

There are 300 000 000+ rows in unit_usage table, 50 000 000+ rows in unit table and 65 000+ rows in region table.
What I want is to query count of **regions** per each **unit_usage**. Something like this:

```
WITH x AS
(
 select u.region_id as region_id, t.title as title
 from unit_usage t join unit u
 on t.unit_id = u.id
)
SELECT title, count(region_id) as found_in_regions
FROM x GROUP BY title;
```

Here' [the DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a7adbedd8fee9f7fd2e42e0140c612bd).

This query runs about 5 minutes. That's too much - my limit is about 10 seconds.
What I've tried:

re-shaping query like:

```
select u.region_id, t.title, count(t.id) 
from unit_usage t join unit u
on t.unit_id = u.id group by u.region_id, t.title;
```

the same execution time.

- setting enable_hashjoin = off; I've got rid of Hash Join and one of Seq Scan, but that doesn't affect execution time

Comment: Is it OLAP or OLTP?

Comment: This is an OLAP part

Comment: It is not possible for query to scan +300 million rows and execute in 10 seconds. You should create additional table with aggregates or add aggregated column to unit table with count of usages. And calculate this aggregates during your ETL. Then your query will become simple full scan by one table.

Comment: It seems so, but at least I'd be happy to half the time.

Comment: Your two queries are not seemed to be equivalent, because in first query you group by title and in the second by title and region_id. Is it so important to have title in group by? Or may be you can just group by region_id?

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to get the logic correct.  If you want to count the number of distinct regions, then I would expect:

> What I want is to query count of regions per each unit_usage.

```
select u.id, count(distinct u.region_id) 
from unit_usage uu join
     unit u
     on t.unit_id = u.id
group by u.id;
```

This will not speed the query.  But at least it should return correct results.  If that is the case, then you can start thinking about how to make it correct.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while I was writing this sample. I **fixed SQL** in both topic / fiddle. SQL (fixed) is correct, it provides desired results: regions related to each individual title in **unit_usage**.

Comment: ```count(distinct u.region_id)``` will be always equal to 1, because you makes grouping by primary key

Comment: @Sergey94 . . . I don't understand your comment.  `u.region_id` has nothing to do with the primary key on `unit_usage`.

Comment: Look at your ```group by uu.id```. You are grouping by primary key of unit_usage. That is why count will be always equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

This query has equivalent results with your second query. It can be faster, because there is less rows to join:

```
with uu as (
  select u.unit_id, u.title, count(*) cnt
    from unit_usage u
   group by u.unit_id, u.title
)
select u.region_id, uu.title, sum(cnt)
  from uu
    inner join unit u
      on uu.unit_id = u.id
 group by u.region_id, uu.title
```

This index may be beneficial for this query (better to test with and without index):

```
create index unit_usage_ix on unit_usage(unit_id, title);
```